# Bash script for showing newly introduced env variables

Tags: bash, shell, posix, portability

I'm making this test script to help me reverse engineer scripts in charge of setting the dev environment.

The script:

```
#env-changes
#!/bin/bash
TESTED_SCRIPT=$1
shift
ENV_BEFORE=$(env | sort)
. $TESTED_SCRIPT
ENV_AFTER=$(env | sort)
diff <(printf '%s\n' "$ENV_BEFORE") <(printf '%s\n' "$ENV_AFTER")
```

Dummy env script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export I_AM_NEW=hello
```

Usage:

```
$ ./env-changes dummy-env-script.sh 
21a22
> I_AM_NEW=hello
```

Currently it only works with `bash`. Suggestions on how to make it more POSIX compilant?

Comment: *Why* does it need to be more POSIX? Are you targetting a platform that does not have bash? Don't waste your time if this is not a real requirement for you.

Comment: @glennjackman I had a general feeling that that is what one should always aim for :) . It isn't a real requirement so far.

Comment: BTW, the `#!` line should be the FIRST line of the script.  If your first line is `#env-changes` as you've posted it, it is only being run by `bash` because `/bin/sh` is the default interpreter and `/bin/sh` is `bash` on your system.  It's not uncommon even on linux systems for `/bin/sh` to be `dash` or `ash` or some other minimalist posix sh (partly because they're much smaller and often faster than `bash`, and because some people see the huge size of bash as a potential security risk due to the larger "attack surface" of large programs vs small programs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the [POSIX `source` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) will only source files from directories in the `PATH`. To get around that, you will need to use a full path:

```
sh ./env-changes ./dummy-env-script.sh
```

Also, the portable version of `source` is `.`:

```
. "$1"
```

Then, the `<()` construct is not POSIX, so you'll need to work around that. For example, you can use temp files:

```
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)
env | sort > "$tmp1"
. "$1"
env | sort > "$tmp2"
diff "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
rm  "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
```

Or, a different approach:

```
ENV_BEFORE=$(env)
. "$1"
ENV_AFTER=$(env)
printf -- '%s\n%s\n' "$ENV_BEFORE" "$ENV_AFTER" | sort | uniq -u
```

Here, we print both variables, sort them, pass them through `uniq -u` which will only print unique lines, printing only the new variable:

```
$ sh ./env-changes ./dummy-env-script.sh 
I_AM_NEW=hello
```